# Calling Java library method with (Object ...) arg list from Scala , retaining type sanity (Shapeless / Scalaz)

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, scalaz, shapeless

I am using the datastax java drver for Cassandra from scala (2.10.4)
to build batches of prepared statements
but have hit the following problem.

Table definition in CQL

```
use ks;
drop table bc_test;
create table bc_test(
  id TEXT,
  id_1 BIGINT,
  c1 COUNTER,
  c2 COUNTER,
  PRIMARY KEY(id, id_1)
);
```

First problem is implicit numeric widening error

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.{ResultSet, ProtocolOptions, Cluster, Session}
import com.datastax.driver.core.RegularStatement
import com.datastax.driver.core.PreparedStatement
import com.datastax.driver.core.BoundStatement
import com.datastax.driver.core.BatchStatement

val c = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build
val sess = c.connect("ks")

val p_bc_test_c1: PreparedStatement = 
  sess.prepare("UPDATE bc_test SET c1 = c1 + ? WHERE id = ? and id_1 = ?")

val batch: BatchStatement = new BatchStatement(BatchStatement.Type.COUNTER);

val id1: Long = 1L
val idText: String = "one"
val c1: Long = 1L

batch.add(p_bc_test_c1.bind(c1, "one", id1))

// which gives the error
scala> batch.add(p_bc_test_c1.bind(c1, "one", id1))
<console>:19: error: implicit numeric widening
              batch.add(p_bc_test_c1.bind(c1, "one", id1))
                                          ^
```

I can get around this using type ascription but wanted to find something a bit nicer
that can also be built into a more generic solution. What I came up with was :

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import shapeless._
import poly._
import syntax.std.tuple._

trait CassandraLongVal
type CassandraLong = java.lang.Long @@ CassandraLongVal
def cassandraLongCol(c : Long): CassandraLong = Tag(c)

trait CassandraIntVal
type CassandraInt = java.lang.Integer @@ CassandraIntVal
def cassandraIntCol(c : Int): CassandraInt = Tag(c)

object ToCassandraType extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseInt     = at[Int](cassandraIntCol(_))
  implicit def caseLong    = at[Long](cassandraLongCol(_))
  implicit def caseString  = at[String](identity)
}

case class Update1(cval: Long, id: String, id1: Long)
val update1Gen = Generic[Update1]

val bUpdate1 = Update1(125L, "two", 1L)

val update1AsArray = update1Gen.to(bUpdate1).map(ToCassandraType).toArray
batch.add(p_bc_test_c1.bind(update1AsArray:_*))
batch.add(p_bc_test_c1.bind(update1AsArray:_*))
sess.execute(batch)
```

This seems to work quite happily and I can use the basic pattern for dozens of table with different columns.
Is this a reasonable approach, or is there a simpler way to get the same outcome whilst trying to keep a handle on the types
and am I abusing scalaz/ shapeless through my (considerable) ignorance.